# How do I disable the first option in a ComboBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

I have made a `combobox` with `DropDownStyle` property to `DropDownList` and I am trying to disable the first option of the dropdown (Read only) as this should be something like "choose an option".

How can I do it?
The equivalent code in HTML should be something like this:

```
<option selected disabled>Select an option</option>
```

[This](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FWMTMZB4KAR3) is just a demo in html of what i actually want to achieve in c#.

[image]
[image]

By the way I am using **visual C# Windows Forms App** (.NET Framework)

Comment: You mean using Razor syntax?

Comment: Could you show us your currently combobox dropdownlist code?

Comment: which project template did u using, `Asp.Net`, `Asp.Net MVC` or any other?

Comment: @ershoaib windows forms app (.NET Framework)

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Comment: @D-Shih it is just design, what i made is a combobox and changed dropdownstyle property to DropDownList

Comment: I don't think this is possibel, at least not without owner-drawing for style and coding the events to prevent selecting a disabled item..

Comment: Winforms and Html? Are you using BrowserControl or something?

Comment: @SeM the html is just to show you to understand my problem. I do not use html. I use visual C# actually.

Comment: Please share actual code you are using (how you bind items to combobox) and call things as they are. You want to disable some items inside `ComboBox` control (well in your case first one), to be not selectable, right?

Comment: Yes just read only. I want to disable the first. See my new screenshot

Comment: If it is not too late consider switching the project from winforms to WPF (since you look like a person who is familiar with html doing WPF is not too big of a logic leap). Doing custom interactions with controls is a lot easier to do, you would just need to use a DataTemplate for the first member that does not allow you to select the option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this:

```
private void comboBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    var yourFont = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9, FontStyle.Regular);

    if (e.Index == 0)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(comboBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(), yourFont, Brushes.LightGray, e.Bounds);
    }
    else
    {
        e.DrawBackground();
        e.Graphics.DrawString(comboBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(), yourFont, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds);
        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    }
}

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

You need to set the [`DrawMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.drawmode?view=netframework-4.7.2) property of the `comboBox` to [`OwnerDrawFixed`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/System.Windows.Forms.DrawMode?view=netframework-4.7.2) also.

Comment: To make it more flexible one can hold a List<int>, maybe in the tag and test like this: `var ok = (List<int>)comboBox1.Tag;
int ix = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
if (ok.Contains(ix)) comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1`

Comment: Make that `notOk` ;-) - Also: Instead of clearing the selection one may want to restore the previous valid selection.

Comment: Is there an easier way? This looks confusing for me

Comment: @GragasIncoming This is the easiest way that I know. Why confusing? You just need to copy and paste the code above, in the `DrawItem` event of your `ComboBox` and set he `DrawMode` property of the `comboBox` to `OwnerDrawFixed`.

Comment: so i double click the form (in the design mode) and add this code?

Comment: @GragasIncoming No. In the Events tab of your combobox look for DrawItem event and double click on it and paste the code there.

Comment: Alright, one note. Index 0 should not be allowed to be clicked as well since it is only for read only.

Comment: @GragasIncoming Make sure that you have also pasted the code for `SelectedIndexChanged`. Just double click on your combobox to generate this event and paste the end part of my code to prevent index 0 to be clicked.

Comment: I get error when adding the code of the  `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` function